# (UWP) Indexing List Causes System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when Accessing ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, combobox, outofrangeexception

I have a problem where indexing a List will break code that is seemingly unrelated to it. Doing anything with the List will cause the exception, but if I just remove the `activePeople[]` the ComboBox code works. In both cases I have looked through all the Lists and made sure that there are values in all of them, so I don't understand how there can be an OutOfRange exception.

The following code only takes parts from the actual code and doesn't follow the same structure, but both `peopleBox` and 'activePeople' will be populated before any of the code runs, and `SelectionChanged()` always runs before `RemovePersonClick()`. Note peopleBox is binded to ComboBox

```
class Person 
{
    public string ID;
    public string Name;
}

ObservableCollection<string> peopleBox = new ObservableCollection<string> { "All" }; // More items are added before any of this code runs
List<Person> activePeople = new List<Person>(); // this also get's populated before any of the other code runs

private void RemovePersonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    int selectedPersonIndex = ComboBox.SelectedIndex;

    if(selectedPersonIndex < 1) return; //Don't do anything if "All" or nothing is selected

    activePeople.RemoveAt(selectedPersonIndex - 1); // -1 because it doesn't contain "All" at the start

    //Both of these throw System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    //Even though I have verified that the indexes exist
    ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0; // 0 index always exists as "All" is never removed, i've even tried -1 which should be nothing, but it throws the error
    peopleBox.RemoveAt(selectedPersonIndex);
}

// This code is always run before the RemovePersonClick method
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    //This causes the issue. If i index activePeople in any way, an error will be thrown in the RemovePersonClick method.
    //Removing this line stops the error. I can't find any link between the two, and I have verified that nothing is out of range.
    string ID = activePeople[0].ID;
}
```

I have tried removing the `activePeople[0]` which did solve the issue, but I need to get the value from `activePeople`. I have checked that values do exist in both the ComboBox and peopleBox, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // -1 because it doesn't contain "All" at the start

So if you remove all items, `activePeople` will become empty, in this situation accessing `activePeople[0]` is invalid, you should handle this exception like this.

```
string ID = activePeople.Count > 0 ? activePeople[0].ID : "All";
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that `RemovePersonClick()` also causes `SelectionChanged()` to fire, which meant that the program was trying to index while the list was empty. I guess adding extra checks for the future and not assuming will help this problem not occur again.